# Array($row['image']) not available in $pdf->image

Tags: php, fpdf

I have a small question..... 
I'm making an FPDF now I want to add an image but how can I get the name of the image from my DB....? 
The code is crashing on the $row['image'] in $pdf->image so i need a $row without this ['image'].
At his moment $row is containing the correct image name! But cannot be used in the $pdf->image. Is there somebody that can help me?

this is my code:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");
$query1 = "SELECT image FROM `ncr_input` WHERE id = 27";
$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query1);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1);
echo $row['image'];

include_once "FPDF/fpdf.php";
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->Image("sitephotos/$row['image']",11,11,35,17.5,"JPG");
$pdf->Output();
```

Comment: Try fixing the path string`'./sitephotos/'.$row['image'],`

Comment: Please share more information, for example, what do ypu mean with _The code is crashing on the $row['image']_? What error do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace the command

```
$pdf->Image("sitephotos/$row['image']",11,11,35,17.5,"JPG");
```

with

```
$pdf->Image("sitephotos/".$row['image'],11,11,35,17.5,"JPG");
```